# Вывод выбранных значений из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно вывести из БД товары по айди, то-есть у товаров есть id (от 6000 до 6999), нужно вывести товары у которых id с 6500 до 6900, делал так но выводит все id:

```
   <?php
   $hostname = "****"; 
   $username = "****"; 
   $password = "****"; 
   $dbName = "****"; 

   mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу  создать соединение");
   mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');

   mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

   $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products_ru_ru";
   $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

   ?>

  <h3 class="title">Тест</h3>
  <div class="module-content">
  <?php
                            while ($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
                            {
                            $marka1 = $row1['product_id'][6500];
                            echo "<div value=\"$marka1\">$marka1</div>";
                            };
                        ?></div>


  </div>
```

Comment: получайте из базы уже нужные строки, `$query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products_ru_ru WHERE product_id BETWEEN 6500 AND 6900";`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сделал как вы посоветовали, получилось:  <h3 class="title">Test</h3>
<div class="module-content">
<?php
        while ($row1=mysql_fetch_row($result1))
        {
           echo $row1[3];
           };
       ?></div>

Comment: Но как сейчас обрамить это все в div? Почему то выдает ошибку при такой записи: while ($row1=mysql_fetch_row($result1))
        {
           echo "<div class="result1">$row1[3]</div>";
           };
       ?></div>

Comment: `while ($row1=mysql_fetch_row($result1)) { echo "<div>{$row1[3]}</div>" }`

Comment: То-есть я вывел из бд записи товаров $row1[3] - где 3 это title, далее мне нужно таким же образом вывести цены этих товаров - $row1[4], и нужно им присвоить классы в диве для верстки

Comment: `echo "<div>{$row1[3]} <span class='price'>{$row1[4]}</span></div>"`